# Print Driver Halts

Tags: windows-10, printer, network-printer

I have a Konica Minolta Bizhub c364e. As I was installing the driver, it the install screen disappeared in the middle of searching for the IP address of that device. What would cause the installation to stop like that?

I am using Windows 10 version 1809 and printer driver version 5.1.3. I used a driver the company had on file and I also used a driver from the Konica Minolta website.

Comment: OS version? Driver version? Where did it come from? Please [edit] the question.

Comment: The OS is windows 10 1803, driver is 5.1.3. My company has a copy of the drive on file and I also got a copy from the Konica Minolta site just to try it. I was able to fix the issue. I did a manual install by adding a printer, then pointing the install to the .inf file. It worked after that.

Comment: Please always [edit] the question to add requested information, not just comments. That said, the 5.1.3.0 driver isn't the latest and it's likely not optimized for newer Windows 10 builds. Have you tried the new PCL6 driver version 5.3.0.0?

Comment: I edited the question as well. I was able to get the printer installed using a different method also added in the previous comment. Thank you for answering back so quickly and for all your help.

Comment: You're welcome. You may also answer your own question describing the method used to install. You can later accept it and get reputation points and I'm sure it'll be helpful for other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way that I found to help me with this problem is to ensure that you're using a driver that is compatible with Windows 10. After I found a Win 10 driver, I stopped receiving this error.